# Async - await - thread expected

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

i Have the following code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run1();
        Run2().Wait();
    }

    static async Task DoAsyncWork()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    static async Task Run2()
    {
        var tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        await DoAsyncWork();
        Console.WriteLine(tid == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    static void Run1()
    {
        var tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        DoAsyncWork().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(tid == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

What will be the output:

1. Sometimes True sometimes false.

   True
2. False

   False
3. True

   Sometimes True sometimes false.
4. True

   True

I think 3 is the correct answer, but when i run the code all time i get:

True

False

I know why the first print is True but anyone can explain me why when i run the code allways i get False? (how i can get True in second print?)

Thank!

Comment: How do you expect it to come back to the first thread?

Answer (score 6):

Console apps do not have a synchronization context so `await` is not able to return to the previous thread. This is why you are seeing a different thread id in `Run2`.

You can read more about this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/).