# async and await thread issue

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I write a program to check if i understand the async-await concept.

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run2().Wait();
    }

    static async Task DoAsyncWork()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    static async Task Run2()
    {
        var tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        await DoAsyncWork();
        Console.WriteLine(tid == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

I am little bit confuse , what will be print?

**I think that we have no guarantee what will be print**

My Explantion:
When `await DoAsyncWork` is call the control return to Main.
after `DoAsyncWork` complete the control return and continue the rest of code after await.
The rest of code can run and we have no gurantee about witch thread run this code.

Actually:
I run this code a lot of time and get `False` print.

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577858/async-await-thread-expected

Comment: *we have no gurantee about witch thread run this code.* If `await` will schedule continuation instead of just continue (as it will do if would see already completed task), then we have guarantee that continuation will be run on one of `ThreadPool` threads. As before `await` it use not `ThreadPool` thread, then it guarantee that thread would be different.

Comment: You really should stop asking the same question again and again. Better read this article instead: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Answer (score 4):

The `await` will use  `SynchronizationContext.Current` to determine how to execute the continuation code.  If there is a value in the current sync context, and the particular implementation of the sync context you have ends up running all code sent to it on a particular thread, then you'll always end up running the code in the same thread.  (The sync context that a winforms or WPF application sets would do this.)

If there is no synchronization context (which is the case in your code), the default will be used, which uses the thread pool, so it could end up running on any thread.  It's also possible for there to be a synchronization context set that doesn't necessarily run all code sent to it on the same thread.  (The sync context an ASP application uses would do this.)

Since, in your code, there is no sync context, the thread pool will be used, and the threads will never be the same.  If you created a message loop that has a synchronization context directing messages to it (like, say, would happen when starting a winforms or WPF application) and called `Run2` from that, then the threads would reliably match.

Comment: So if the context is the same before and after the await keyword so the threads will be same?

Comment: @maz If you have not default context before `await`, then it is up to that context in which thread and context continuation will be invoked, assuming that `await` have something to await for and not already completed task, in which case execution will be continued in current thread.

Comment: @PetSerAl can you give examlpe, assume that the context is asp context?

Comment: @maz Example of what exactly? And I am not particularly familiar with ASP context implementation details.